# Show $\alpha G^a_{\mu\nu} \widetilde{G^a_{\mu\nu}}$ can be written as a total derivative.

Tags: tensors

I'm trying to show that $\alpha G^a_{\mu\nu} \widetilde{G^a_{\mu\nu}}$ can be written as a total derivative, where 
$$\begin{equation} G^a_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu} G^a_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}G^a_{\mu}-gf_{bca}G^b_{\mu}G^c_{\nu} \end{equation} $$
$$\widetilde{G^a_{\mu\nu}} = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}G^a_{\lambda\rho} $$
And $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita symbol. Then expand $G^a_{\lambda\rho}$ using the first equation, multiply the two and expand the brackets:
$$\frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho} (\partial_{\lambda}G^a_{\rho}\partial_{\mu}G^a_{\nu}-\partial_{\lambda}G^a_{\rho}\partial_{\nu}G^a_{\mu}-\partial_{\lambda}G^a_{\rho}gf_{bca}G^b_{\mu}G^c_{\nu}-\partial_{rho}G^a_{\lambda}\partial_{\mu}G^a_{\nu}+\partial_{\rho}G^a_{\lambda}\partial_{\nu}G^a_{\mu}+\partial_{\rho}G^a_{\lambda}gf_{bca}G^b_{\mu}G^c_{\nu}-gf_{bca}G^b_{\lambda}G^c_{\rho}\partial_{\mu}G^a_{\nu}+gf_{bca}G^b_{\lambda}G^c_{\rho}\partial_{\nu}G^a_{\mu}+g^2f^2_{bca}G^b_{\lambda}G^c_{\rho}G^b_{\mu}G^c_{\nu})$$

So that looks a mess, but because the Levi-Civita symbol is antisymmetric that equals
$$\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}(4\partial_{\lambda}G^a_{\rho}\partial_{\mu}G^a_{\nu}+2\partial_{\rho}G^a_{\lambda}gf_{bca}G^b_{\mu}G^c_{\nu}+2gf_{bca}G^b_{\lambda}G^c_{\rho}\partial_{\nu}G^a_{\mu}+g^2f^2_{bca}G^b_{\lambda}G^c_{\rho}G^b_{\mu}G^c_{\nu})$$

What it's meant to be, somehow, is
$$\partial_{\mu}\left(\alpha \epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}G^a_{\nu}(G^a_{\lambda\rho} +\frac{1}{3}g f_{bca}G^b_{\lambda}G^c_{\rho}) \right)$$

But I really, really can't see how you'd get there!

Comment: You have messed up with your indices. What is $f_{bca}^2G^bG^cG^bG^c$ supposed to be? There should only be two of any index in any given term! When you compute $G\tilde{G}$ remember to use different dummy indices when you subtitute the expression for $G$ in that for $\tilde{G}$, e.g. $\tilde{G} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon [\ldots - gf_{b'c'a'}G^{b'}G^{c'}]$ so $b'$ and $c'$ instead of using $b$ and $c$ (since those are already used up).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
$\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}$
$\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathrm{Tr}\,}$

Switch to math conventions (who can deal with all those factors of $\i$ and $g$?):
$$\begin{align}
A^a_{\mu}&=-\i g G^a_{\mu}\\
F^a_{\mu\nu}&=-\i g G^a_{\mu\nu}\\
\tau_a&=\i T_a \\
c^a_{bc}&=-f^a_{bc}\\
[\tau_a,\tau_b]&=c^c_{ab}\tau_c\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Let 
$$\kappa_{ab}=\langle \tau_a,\tau_b\rangle \propto \Tr \tau_a\tau_b$$
be the components of the Killing form in negative-definite convention.

I freely use the notation of Lie algebra-valued forms:
$$\begin{align}\langle \alpha \wedge \beta \rangle&=\langle \tau_a,\tau_b\rangle \alpha^a\wedge \beta^b=\kappa_{ab}\alpha^a\wedge\beta^b \\
[\alpha\wedge\beta]&=[\tau_a,\tau_b]\alpha^a\wedge\beta^b=\tau_cc^c_{ab}\alpha^a\wedge\beta^b\text{.}
\end{align}$$

With these conventions,
$$\begin{align}F&=\d A +\tfrac{1}{2}[A\wedge A]\\
F^a_{\mu\nu}&=2\partial_{[\mu}A^a_{\nu]}+c^a_{bc}A^{b}_{[\mu}A^c_{\nu]}
\end{align}$$

Define the **Chern–Weil $4$-form** $W$
$$\begin{align}
W&=\langle F\wedge F\rangle \\ W_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}&=6\kappa_{ab}  F_{[\mu\nu}^a F_{\rho\sigma]}^b
\end{align}$$
and the **Chern–Simons $3$-form** $S$
$$\begin{align}S&=\langle A\wedge F\rangle -\tfrac{1}{6}\langle A\wedge [A\wedge A]\rangle \\
S_{\nu\rho\sigma}&=3\kappa_{ab}A^a_{[\nu} F^b_{\rho\sigma]} -\kappa_{ab}c^{b}_{cd}A_{[\nu}^a A_{\rho}^c A_{\sigma]}^d\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Then the task is to show
$$\begin{align}
W&=\d S\\
W_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}&=4\partial_{[\mu}S_{\nu\rho\sigma]}
\end{align}$$

Differentiating the individual terms of $S$ gives
$$\begin{split}\d\langle A\wedge F\rangle &=\langle \d A\wedge F\rangle -\langle A \wedge \d F\rangle\\
&=\langle (F-\tfrac{1}{2}[A\wedge A])\wedge F\rangle +\langle A \wedge [A\wedge F]\rangle\\
&=(\langle F\wedge F\rangle-\tfrac{1}{2}\langle [A\wedge A]\wedge F\rangle) +\langle [A \wedge A]\wedge F\rangle\\
&=\langle F\wedge F\rangle+\tfrac{1}{2}\langle [A\wedge A]\wedge F\rangle
\end{split}$$

$$\begin{split}\d\langle A\wedge [A\wedge A]\rangle &=\langle \d A\wedge [A\wedge A]\rangle -\langle A\wedge [\d A\wedge A]\rangle + \langle A\wedge [A\wedge \d A]\rangle\\
&=3\langle [A\wedge A]\wedge \d A\rangle \\
&=3\left(\langle [A\wedge A]\wedge F\rangle -\tfrac{1}{2} \langle [A\wedge A]\wedge [A\wedge A]\rangle\right)\\
&=3\langle [A\wedge A]\wedge F\rangle\text{.}
\end{split}$$

The sum is
$$\begin{split}\d S &=\d\langle A\wedge F\rangle -\tfrac{1}{6}\d \langle A\wedge [A\wedge A]\rangle\\
&=(\langle F\wedge F\rangle+\tfrac{1}{2}\langle [A\wedge A]\wedge F\rangle)-\tfrac{1}{2}\langle [A\wedge A]\wedge F\rangle\\
&=\langle F \wedge F\rangle \\
&= W\text{.}
\end{split}$$

(This proof is an adaptation of [Freed (1992)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9206021.pdf), Proposition 1.27.)

Aside from the usual calculus of differential forms (or Ricci calculus of antisymmetric tensors, if you want to use index notation), the important ingredients are the *Jacobi identity*

$$\begin{align}[\alpha\wedge[\beta\wedge\gamma]]&=[[\alpha\wedge\beta]\wedge\gamma]+(-1)^{\lvert\alpha\rvert\lvert\beta\rvert}[\beta\wedge[\alpha\wedge\gamma]]\\
c^a_{ub}c^b_{vw}&=c^a_{bw}c^{b}_{uv}+c^a_{vb}c^b_{aw}\text{,}
\end{align}$$

*invariance of the Killing form*

$$\begin{align}
\langle [\alpha\wedge \beta]\wedge \gamma \rangle +(-1)^{\lvert\alpha\rvert \lvert \beta \rvert}\langle\beta \wedge[\alpha\wedge\gamma]\rangle &=0\\
\kappa_{aw}c^a_{uv}+\kappa_{va}c^a_{uw}&=0\text{,}
\end{align}$$

and the *second Bianchi identity*
$$\begin{align}\d F+[A\wedge F]&=0 \\
3\partial_{[\nu}F^a_{\rho\sigma]}+3c^a_{bc}A^b_{[\nu}F^c_{\rho\sigma]} &=0\text{.}
\end{align}$$